# Write unformatted data to file with fstream

Tags: c++, sockets, fstream

I'm trying to transfer a file over between sockets. I use a 1MB file created through /dev/urandom on linux. With this file, I am able to transmit data through the client successfully but when I write the data into a file, the output is incomplete. The command I am using is:

```
 myFile << data;
```

I think what may be happening is that "<<" is not accepting unformatted data. Is there an alternative to "<<" that accepts unformatted data?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. A single line of code doesn't give us enough information. We need a complete, runnable program. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer for writing the size of a vector before the vector, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::ofstream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) (`std::fstream` and `std::ofstream` inherit the `write` function from `std::basic_ostream`).

```cpp
myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data), sizeof(data));
```

For raw binary data `vector<uint8_t> data` you can write the whole vector at once:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> data{};

//Fill data...

myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data()), data.size());
```

Structures are a little different:

```cpp
std::vector<Foo> data{};

//Fill data...

myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data()), data.size() * sizeof(Foo));
```

Regardless, you need to prepend the write with the number of elements in the data buffer so you know how big it is when you want to get it back out:

```cpp
const auto buffer_size = data.size();
myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer_size), sizeof(buffer_size));
```